# Accessing z-value of Coordinates for Spring NVC with Hibernate Spatial

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, oracle-spatial, jts

I have a Spring MVC application that I am building, using an Oracle Spatial database which contains 3D geometries. I'm using Hibernate Spatial to access it, but as I am new to Spring (and relatively new to Java), I am finding it difficult to access the z-coordinate for my view. Code below:

### Deposit.java

```
package com.example.project.model;

 import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point
 import ...

@Entity
@Table(name="DEPOSITS")
public class Deposit {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private int id;

  @Column(name = "NAME")
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "GEOM",updatable = false)
  @Type(type="org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
  private Point geometry;

  public Point getGeometry() {
    return geometry;
  }
}
```

### DepositController.java

```
package com.example.project;

import ...

@Controller
public class DepositController {
  private DepositService depositService;

  @Autowired(required = true)
  @Qualifier(value = "depositService")
  public void setDepositService(DepositService ds) { 
    this.depositService = ds;
  }

  //Index
  @RequestMapping(value = "/deposits", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String listDeposits(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("listDeposits", this.depositService.listDeposits());
    return "deposits/index";
  }
}
```

### deposits/index.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Deposits Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <c:if test="${!empty listDeposits}">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Deposit ID</th>
          <th>Deposit Name</th>
          <th>Longitude</th>
          <th>Latitude</th>
          <th>Height</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${listDeposits}" var="deposit">
          <tr>
            <td>${deposit.id}</td>
            <td>${deposit.name}</td>
            <td>${deposit.geometry.x}</td>
            <td>${deposit.geometry.y}</td>
            <td>${deposit.geometry.coordinate.z}</td>
          </tr>
        </c:forEach>
      </table>
    </c:if>
  </body>
</html>
```

I know that the Point type for JTS does not expose the z-coordinate, and that it can accessed through the coordinates object. The code `deposit.getGeometry().getCoordinates().z` works, how do I make it work for my .jsp view?

Thanks

Comment: What type of Point class are you using? i.e. including the package name.

Comment: `com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that `${deposit.geometry.x}` is being rewritten into `deposit.getGeometry().getX()` and getX() is a method that exists on that class, so it works.

Similarly, `${deposit.geometry.coordinate.z}` would be rewritten to `deposit.getGeometry().getCoordinate().getZ()`, which is not a method that exists.

I would just add getters for X, Y and Z to the Deposit class and then use

```
${deposit.x}
${deposit.y}
${deposit.z}
```

Comment: Good to know I'm doing the right thing, as that's what I ended up doing! But I was wondering whether JSTL could access the z-value without requiring a getter.

Regardless, accessing the z-value is pointless due to this bug:

http://www.hibernatespatial.org/jira/browse/HIBSPA-117